# Browser plugin dictionaries: Click word to translate, instead of following link

Tags: browser, links, dictionary

The Google Dictionary plugin supports translation of words in a webpage. The translation is triggered by double-clicking or word selection.

But if the word to be translated is part of a link, clicking, double-clicking or selecting the word instructs the browser to follow the link, as opposed to triggering the translation of the word by Google translator.

Yet it is often the case that in the international press headlines are clickable and link to extended news pieces.

Any suggestions to avoid following the link and instead getting Google dictionary to translate intra-link words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `Alt`+`mouse drag` on the word to be selected, within a hyperlink, to select the required word.

Tested to work with Firefox and Chrome (both Windows and Linux).
On Microsoft Edge: Not working.

Comment: Thanks. Solved. On Chrome with Google Dictionary plugin installed, Alt+mouse drag allows for selection of words in a hyperlinked sentece without browing to the linked page. The dictionary displays then the translation for the word.